# How to round and divide floating values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a floating point value, which i want to convert to no decimal numbers. In this case it should be 120 Then i want to divide the resulting number by 8, round this number up to no decimal numbers again and store the resulting value in a variable, which should be 15 in this case.

my approach logs 15 in this case as needed, but it still has decimals at other values

```
public value1 = 120.09405305
public value2

function()
{
this.value2 = +this.value1.toFixed(0) / 8
 console.log(this.value2) 
}
```

Project is in typescript

Comment: The script does indeed output 15.

Comment: yes it does, but it still has decimals at any other value

Comment: Why cant you use a Math rounding function, why toFixed(0)?

Comment: Your tofixed is converting to a string, and then you divide.  You want to look at Math.round Math.ceil or Math.trunc to do your rounding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) to round your value from a float to an integer without transforming the type of the value.

```js
let startValue = 120.09405305;
let roundedValue = Math.round(startValue)
let dividedValue = roundedValue / 8;
let roundedDividedValue = Math.round(dividedValue)

console.log(startValue, roundedValue, dividedValue, roundedDividedValue);
```